# Redland context in Virtuoso

Tags: rdf, virtuoso, redland

I'm using the Redland Python bindings to add triples to Virtuoso `RDF.Storage(storage_name='virtuoso')` and am trying to understand how context is implemented. I am getting some surprising results.

If I add triples with:

```
model.add_statements(context=something)
```

I can get them all back with:

```
model.as_stream(context=something)
```

as expected. However, if I create a new model with the same storage and try this:

```
for stmt in model: 
    print stmt
```

I get no result, as if the model is empty. Also, when I try the following:

```
model.remove_statements_with_context(context=something)
for stmt in model.as_stream(context=something): 
    print stmt
```

I still get back all of the triples; they weren't removed as I expected them to be.

Finally, when I try simple SPARQL queries that should match some of the triples stored with context, I get no result.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on behind the scenes with Redland contexts and Virtuoso?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Virtuoso [trace_on() function](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_trace_on.html) to enable queries etc being passed to Virtuoso to be logged in the `virtuoso.log` file for review.

This should help you see what is being passed by the Redland layer, and any errors, etc., that might be occurring.

We haven't done any testing with the Redland Python bindings to my knowledge, but we do have a `C`-based test program in the [Virtuoso open source tree](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/) that was [used for testing our Redland Storage provider](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFDriverRedland).

I hope this helps ...